# Javascript Promise.all() method to fire after all errors and success – surprised that finally() doesnt do this

Tags: javascript, promise

I need a method to fire after all success and fails and I would expect .finally() to do this but I was surprised that it does not. Instead, it fires on the reject. Example code

```js
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('three fails');
    reject({ data: 'three' });
  }, 2000);
});

var p4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('four succeeds');
    resolve({ data: 'four' });
  }, 3000);
});

Promise.all([p3, p4])
  .finally(() => console.log('Promise.all() finally fires.'));
```

gives the following console logs in this order

```
three fails
Promise.all().finally fires.
four succeeds
```

My only alternative would be to possible have .then and .catch both fire resolves but that would be pretty clunky.

Could someone point out a method that does what I'm looking for and/or have an explanation why finally is failing to fire after all promises complete?

Comment: The Promise returned by `Promise.all` will be rejected as soon as one of the Promies passed to it is rejected, even if there are still Promises that are pending. And `finally`  will be called as soon as the Promise returned by `Promise.all`  is either `rejected`  or `resolved`.

Comment: I was just reading the duplicate ticket, I'll close this. Thanks